# A sequence on a line through the origin in $\mathbb{C}$ must converge on that line?

Tags: geometry, analysis, complex-analysis

Does this make sense?

Lemma: Consider a sequence $(z_n) \subset \mathbb{C}$. If $z_n \to z$ and $Arg(z_n) = Arg(z_m)$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $Arg(z) = Arg(z_n)$.

Proof: Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The line passing through the origin and $z_n$ is bijectively isometric to $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore complete. Thus any sequence on that line must converge on that line.

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: Looks good to me too. Unless this is homework, in which case it may depend on what your grader is expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another argument: Let $\theta = e^{-i\operatorname{Arg}z_1}$, and $y_n = \theta z_n$. Then $y_n \to \theta z$ and $\operatorname{Im} y_n = 0$ for all $n$ (in fact, $y_n \in [0,\infty)$). It follows that $\operatorname{Im} \theta z = 0$, and so $z = r e^{i\operatorname{Arg}z_1}$ for some $r \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: That works too, and it's quite a bit simpler than my idea.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest would be to note that $R=\{ r e^{i \operatorname{Arg} z_1 } \}_{r \in [0,\infty)}$ is closed, and $z_n \in R$ for all $n$. (Also note a tiny point that it may be the case that $z_n \to 0$, in which case $\operatorname{Arg} z$ is not defined.)